# MINGW Compiler for C - cl is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: c, terminal, compiler-errors, mingw, mingw-w64

MinGW is installed for C with the "bin" added to PATH in Environment Variables.
"g++ --version" feeds back with version as expected, however when using the "cl" it shows an error

"cl is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Comment: Why do you want to use `cl`? It's the Microsoft Visual Studio C++ compiler. Do you have Visual Studio installed? With the proper paths set up?

Comment: Sorry for any grammatical errors. No, It is not, In the tutorial the C program was compiled with `cl`. I am using Atom for editing and was attempting to use the terminal to compile the code.

Comment: With MinGW the GNU C compiler is called `gcc`, it's the one you should use to build C programs. If you follow a tutorial that tells you to use `cl` then it's telling you to use the Visual Studio C++ compiler. You need to exchange all `cl` invocations with `gcc` invocations. Possibly changing the flags and options passes, since they are mostly not directly compatible.